# Open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) even with permissions

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I know there are many other posts with this issue, but none seem to solve mine. I am trying to create a file on `Enviroment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`, email that file, and then delete it. However, I am getting an error when I initialize the file output stream `fos = new FileOutputStream(file);`.

The error I get is:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /CheckListReport_2015_07_19.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

In my manifest I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` outside of the applications tag

Below is the code:

```
    String report = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    File file = new File(path, "CheckListReport_" + report + ".txt");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        String lineToWrite;
        for (Map.Entry entry : CheckboxHandler.data.entrySet()) {
            lineToWrite = entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + "\n";
            fos.write(lineToWrite.getBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String subject = "CheckListReport_" + report + ".txt";

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"checklistreportdata@gmail.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(new File(path, "CheckListReport_" + report + ".txt").toString()));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

    file.delete();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Try this code to read files from `Download` directory:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

File file = new File(path, "CheckListReport_" + report + ".txt");
```

Change this:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/CheckListReport_" + report + ".txt"));
```

to:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(new File(path, "CheckListReport_" + report + ".txt").toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited my post with the current code. When I click send it says `Unfortunately Gmail has stopped`

Comment: @Brejuro means now you are able to access that file. correct your path at email sending point too

Comment: I figured, do you know what I'm doing wrong though? `emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path.toString() + "CheckListReport_" + report + ".txt"));` and 
        `emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path.toString() + "CheckListReport_" + report + ".txt"));`

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, I made that change and still get Gmail crashing. I'll update my post with code